# Ant mapper and retaining folder structure

Tags: java, ant

Not sure if there's documentation out there specifically for this, couldn't find it after perusing the ant docs and experimenting a bit, but the main just is this:

Let's say in my Ant build I want to collect all the images in a certain folder and all subfolders in that folder so I can run them through ImageMagick to convert and resize for mobile images.  I use

```
<apply executable="\pathtoImageMagick\convert">
  <fileset dir="${from.dir}/${dir.publish}/${dir.images}" />
  <srcfile />
  <arg value="-resize" />
  <arg value="25%" />
  <targetfile />
  <mapper type="glob" from="*" to="${from.dir}/${dir.publish}/${dir.images}/mobile.*" />
</apply>
```

This works for first-level files, such that beside test.jpg I get mobile.test.jpg.

Unfortunately, if I have an image in a subfolder, say test.jpg in the folder `${from.dir}/${dir.publish}/${dir.images}/home` and I want it to go to `${from.dir}/${dir.publish}/${dir.images}/home/mobile.test.jpg`, how do I do this?  It tried to create `${from.dir}/${dir.publish}/${dir.images}/mobile.home/test.jpg`, which isn't correct.

Any ideas from someone who has experience with Ant and mapper?  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glob mapping isn't useful here, because you want to interpose something in the middle of the matched 'atom'.  There is an example in the Ant documentation of this type of mapping that uses a [`regexpmapper`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#regexp-mapper), something like:

```
<mapper type="regexp" from="(.*)/([^/]+)" to="\1/mobile.\2" />
```

The `from` says: grab the directory path to `\1`, grab the filename to `\2`.  Then in the `to` the prefix is inserted.

Comment: Cool, I thought maybe I'd have to go the regex route.  Unfortunately the above regex doesn't do it, but I'm sure I can figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but are you also trying to move/copy the images from one directory to another as a part of this?

If not, and you just need to map all `*.jpg` files in any subdirectory of `${from.dir}/${dir.publish}/${dir.images}` to `mobile.*.jpg`, then try this:

```
<fileset includes="${from.dir}/${dir.publish}/${dir.images}/**/*" />
...
<mapper type="glob" from="*" to="mobile.*" />
```

The `<fileset>` element should include all files in all subdirectories of that path, and the mapper should prepend "mobile." to it's filename.

Comment: The second part is right, I guess the easiest way of saying it is prepending mobile. to every filename while retaining the folder structure. Tried doing the above and got the following error: path_to_my_image/**/* does not exist

Comment: Just to make sure, you replaced `<fileset dir=` with `<fileset includes=` also?

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out.  Changed it, which seems like a better direction, but then it tells me 'No directory specific for fileset'.  Is there a way to split the includes above so that we can put half in a dir and half in a includes param?

Comment: @jimlamiell `<fileset dir="${from.dir}/${dir.publish}/${dir.images}"><include name="**/*"/></fileset>` is maybe what you need.

Comment: Tried a bunch of variations, still no go.